# How does the LLVM InstVisitor traverse IR?

Tags: llvm

I have a working InstVisitor, thanks to the answer to my [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32830657/how-do-i-correclty-implement-an-llvm-instvisitor). Does LLVM make these InstVisitors traverse the IR using DFS or BFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DFS. Check the source here (relevant lines 88 to 108):
http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/InstVisitor_8h_source.html#l00088

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed.