# Using dyn_cast in for loop

Tags: c++, templates, llvm

I'm working on LLVM project and have such code:

```cpp
if (auto *var = dyn_cast<type_0>(args) {
// code    
} else if (auto *var = dyn_cast<type_1>(args) {
// same code as in first `if`
} else if (auto *vat = dyn_cast<type_2>(args) {
//same code as in first `if`
}// and etc.
```

Is it possible to convert these `if/else` statements to something like this?

```cpp
auto types[] = {type_0, type_1, type_2, ... };
for (auto type : types) {
    if (apply(type, args)) {
        break;
    }
}

bool apply(type, args) {
//code from first `if` statement
}
```

Comment: Not possible in the way you have written it, but there are certain template metaprogramming techniques that allow you to create an "array" of types and then instantiate a function for each type in that "array".

Comment: While @Alan_Birtles's code below will work (also check out [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) IMO), I would get really suspicious about your class designs if this is *necessary* because you need RTTI for this, which Google has some decent advice about: [Google C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Run-Time_Type_Information__RTTI_), in particular their comment that "Decision trees based on type are a strong indication that your code is on the wrong track.".  I'd be re-thinking your class hierarchy and design.

Answer (score 1):

With some funky fold expression magic it's possible to do this (derived from https://www.foonathan.net/2020/05/fold-tricks/). I've used `dynamic_cast` for an easier demo but I presume `dyn_cast` works the same way:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo> 

class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {};
};

class Sub1 : public Base {};
class Sub2 : public Base {};
class Sub3 : public Base {};
class Sub4 : public Base {};

template<typename T>
bool visitor(const T& t)
{
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << "\n";
    return true;
}

template <typename Base, typename ...T>
bool visit(Base& base)
{
    return ((dynamic_cast<T*>(&base) ? (visitor(*dynamic_cast<T*>(&base)), false) : true) && ...);
}

int main()
{
    Sub2 sub;
    Base& base = sub;
    visit<Base, Sub1, Sub2, Sub3, Sub4>(base);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest LLVM-ish way is to use [InstVisitor](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1InstVisitor.html); [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32833111) contains the typical declaration and you can find several examples if you search for code in LLVM that inherits InstVisitor in that way.

Then you just make an instance of your InstVisitor subclass and tell it to visit() any module, function, basic block or instruction, and it'll call the right visitFoo() for that instruction or for each instruction.